# How to get commitMessage from gerrit REST API use JAVA

Tags: java, gerrit

I want to use java connect [Gerrit REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html), so i find the opensource **[gerrit-rest-java-client](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-rest-java-client)**. But i don't know how to query the changes **commitMessage**.

My simple code is as follows

```
GerritRestApiFactory gerritRestApiFactory = new GerritRestApiFactory();
GerritAuthData.Basic authData = new GerritAuthData.Basic("Gerrit", "User", "password");

GerritApi gerritApi = gerritRestApiFactory.create(authData);

List<ChangeInfo> changes = gerritApi.changes().query("status:merged").withLimit(1).get();

for (ChangeInfo cc : changes) {
    System.out.println("subject:" + cc.subject);
    System.out.println("changeId:" + cc.changeId);
    System.out.println("commitMessage:");
}
```

Comment: I survey Gerrit REST API find Revision Endpoints API can get commit message, but i use RevisionApi not find any method or variable can get message.
`ChangeApi ccapi = gerritApi.changes() .id("PROJECTBASE~BCX10A51~I031e50eb06c10638b914abb7a5d4‌​31e49b19abb8"); RevisionApi rr = ccapi.revision("031e50eb06c10638b914abb7a5d431e49b19abb8");
`

Comment: You have to use GerritApi as ~gerritApi.changes().query("query").get();~ passing the query, for commitMessage, form the query as documented here - https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-commit

Answer (score 2):

You need to [query changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes) adding the "&o=CURRENT_REVISION" to get commit SHA-1 of the current revision (see more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#query-options)). Then you need to use the [Get Commit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-commit) endpoint to finally get the commit message.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know use Get Commit can get the commit message, so i use the RevisionApi class try to get the **commit message**, But [RevisionApi sourcecode](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-rest-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/extensions/api/changes/RevisionApi.java) i don't see any about commit message method or variable.